# How can I reduce memory usage when rendering a PDF page into a CGBitmapContext?

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, core-graphics

I'm using the code below to render a preview of a PDF page. However it is using loads of memory (2-3MB per page).

In the device logs I see:

```
<Error>: CGBitmapContextInfoCreate: unable to allocate 2851360 bytes for bitmap data
```

I really don't need the bitmap to be rendered in 8bits per color channel. How can I change the code to have it rendered in grayscale or less bits per channel?

I would also be fine with a solution where the bitmap is rendered in a maximum resolution of x/y and then the resulting image is zoomed to the requested size. The PDF will be rendered in detail afterwards by a `CATiledLayer` anyway.

Also according to Apple's documentation, `CGBitmapContextCreate()` returns NIL if the context cannot be created (because of memory). But in MonoTouch there is only the constructor to create a context, hence I'm unable to check if creation failed or not.
If I was able to, I could just skip the pretender image.

```
UIImage oBackgroundImage= null;
using(CGColorSpace oColorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB())
// This is the line that is causing the issue.
using(CGBitmapContext oContext = new CGBitmapContext(null, iWidth, iHeight, 8, iWidth * 4, oColorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst))
{
    // Fill background white.
    oContext.SetFillColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
    oContext.FillRect(oTargetRect);

    // Calculate the rectangle to fit the page into. 
    RectangleF oCaptureRect = new RectangleF(0, 0, oTargetRect.Size.Width / fScaleToApply, oTargetRect.Size.Height / fScaleToApply);
    // GetDrawingTransform() doesn't scale up, that's why why let it calculate the transformation for a smaller area
    // if the current page is smaller than the area we have available (fScaleToApply > 1). Afterwards we scale up again.
    CGAffineTransform oDrawingTransform = oPdfPage.GetDrawingTransform(CGPDFBox.Media, oCaptureRect, 0, true);

    // Now scale context up to final size.
    oContext.ScaleCTM(fScaleToApply, fScaleToApply);
    // Concat the PDF transformation.
    oContext.ConcatCTM(oDrawingTransform);
    // Draw the page.
    oContext.InterpolationQuality = CGInterpolationQuality.Medium;
    oContext.SetRenderingIntent (CGColorRenderingIntent.Default);
    oContext.DrawPDFPage(oPdfPage);

    // Capture an image.
    using(CGImage oImage = oContext.ToImage())
    {
        oBackgroundImage = UIImage.FromImage( oImage );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I really don't need the bitmap to be rendered in 8bits per color channel.

...

```
using(CGColorSpace oColorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB())
```

Have you tried to provide a different color space ?

> where the bitmap is rendered in a maximum resolution of x/y

...

```
using(CGBitmapContext oContext = new CGBitmapContext(null, iWidth, iHeight, 8, iWidth * 4, oColorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst))
```

You can control the bitmap size too and other parameters that directly affect how much memory is required by the bitmap.

> Also according to Apple's documentation, CGBitmapContextCreate() returns NIL if the context cannot be created (because of memory).

If an invalid object (like `null`) is returned then the C# instance will have an `Handle` equals to `IntPtr.Zero`. This is true for any ObjC object, since `init` can return `nil` and a .NET constructor cannot return `null`.

Comment: I made an interesting discovery: the issue is on iPad 3 only! On iPad 3 b/c of the high resolution, the bitmaps use 2.8MB of RAM. On iPad 1 and 2, the same bitmap uses 700k. I think that there is a problem in iOS - it SHOULD really warn me but it just dies without any warning. I'm limiting the maximum bitmap resolution to 700k now.

Answer (score 2):

> Also according to Apple's documentation, CGBitmapContextCreate() returns NIL if the context cannot be created (because of memory). But in MonoTouch there is only the constructor to create a context, hence I'm unable to check if creation failed or not. If I was able to, I could just skip the pretender image.

This is actually easy:

```
CGBitmapContext context;
try {
    context = new CGBitmapContext (...);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    context = null;
}

if (context != null) {
    using (context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

or you could also just surround the entire using clause in an exception handler:

```
try {
    using (var context = new CGBitmapContext (...)) {
        ...
    }
} catch {
    // we failed
    oBackgroundImage = null;
}
```

Comment: Then Sebastien's solution who is checking if context.Handle == IntPtr.Zero cannot work because "context" would not be a valid reference. Who of you two is right? :-)

Comment: @Krumelur: Both. It depends if the class library either does a check (very uncommon) and do some additional calls (more common) on the instance created with a null `Handle`. If it's used (e.g. internally) then you *might* get an exception (before you get the chance to check the `Handle`) but you cannot depend on getting an exception *only* to trap invalid instances. OTOH if the .ctor throws you won't be able to to ask for it's handle ;-). Changing the above `if (context != null) {` for `if (context != null and context.Handle != IntPtr.Zero) {` will cover both cases.

Comment: @Krumelur: Sebastien is right for the general case, but in this particular case (CGBitmapContext/CGContext), the handle is checked upon construction (you're running into this exception: https://github.com/mono/maccore/blob/master/src/CoreGraphics/CGContext.cs#L136)